# Socket IO socket.on is not working after reconnection

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Whenever client turns on the remote management, The polling should start with the server ( Admin ). When the polling is started admin can send message to the client to turn on the VPN connection then send back the IP address generated by VPN back to the admin. This is what I'm trying to achieve right now I'm trying to send the static IP value but later I'll include the operations required for VPN. So basically I want to start the polling with admin when the client turns on the remote management and then admin sends message to turn on VPN, then receive the generated ip from client. I've created socket connection through node (server) and python (client) using socket.io, I am unable to print the message after receiving the message from the client after reconnection inside the post route. again when I restart the server It starts working but when the client disconnects and connects again that socket.on inside the post route is not working.

This is the server code :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);

var io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
  serveClient: false,
});

app.set("socketio", io);
app.use(express.json());
const activeUsers = [];
io.sockets.on("connection", (socket) => {

  socket.on("connected", (userid) => {
    //capturing the id
    socket.userId = userid;
    activeUsers[userid] = socket.id;
    console.log(activeUsers);
    socket.join(userid);

    //printing socket rooms!
    console.log(socket.rooms);

    //emitting the message to the client
    io.sockets.to(userid).emit("Hey", "data");

    //receiving message from the client
    socket.on("python", (txt) => {
      console.log(txt);
    });


    //post api to send the vpn messsage and receive the ip
    app.post("/turnonvpn", async (req, res) => {
      let result = await req.body.status;
      let roomNum = await req.body.roomNum;
      console.log(result, roomNum);
      if (result === true) {
        io.sockets.in(roomNum).emit("vpnon", "turnonvpn");
        **socket.on("generatedip", (txt) => {
          console.log(txt);
        });**
        res.send({ status: ipval });
      } else {
        socket.disconnect();
        res.send({ status: "no" });
      }
    });
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Disconnected");
  });

  socket.on("forceclose", (txt) => {
    socket.disconnect();
  });
});

server.listen("3001", () => {
  console.log("running");
});
```

This is client code :

```
from requests import request
import socketio
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

sio = socketio.Client(reconnection=True, handle_sigint=True)


@sio.event
def connect():
    print('Polling Started with server')
    sio.emit("connected", 0)


@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("Disconnected")


@app.route('/pollingstatus', methods=['POST'])
async def rmpolling():
    data = request.get_json()
    status = data['status']
    print(status)
    if status == "True":
        try:
            sio.connect('http://localhost:3001', transports=['websocket'])
            sio.emit("python", "I'm from pythin")
            return ({'status': True, 'result': "Polling success"})
        except:
            print("Error in Polling aka Socket IO")
            # sio.disconnect()
            sio.emit("forceclose", "forceclose")
            return ({'status': False, 'result': 'error'})
    else:
        sio.emit("forceclose", "forceclose")
        # sio.disconnect()
        return ({'status': False, "result": "userClosed"})


@sio.on("Hey")
def on_message(txt):
    print(txt)


@sio.on("vpnon")
def on_message(txt):
    print(txt)
    if txt == 'turnonvpn':
        print("Generating VPN")
        sio.emit('generatedip', {"ip": '123.156.3423'})
        print("Sent IP")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Somebody help me to fix this issue, I've shared the code as well. socket.on is not working inside the post api when the client reconnects to the server until the server gets restart.
The problem is with the node server not with the python which I'm aware of.

Comment: What does "client turns on remote management mean"?

Comment: What does "polling should start with the server" mean?

Comment: When you say "admin sends message to turn on VPN", what does that mean?

Comment: You are using terms that mean something to you, but not to us.  Please describe in terms of client and server actions and requests exactly what sequence you want to happen.

Comment: I'd suggest you write down (in your question) a series of steps that are what you would tell another programmer or a contractor you were hiring to write this for you.  You should write it assuming they nothing about your application or your internal terminology.  This is how you write a clear question that we can then help with.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your code organized, you register a new `app.post()` handler for every single socket that connects.   Since these are matched in the order they were registered, that means that ONLY the first one will ever see the request and thus only the first socket that ever connects will work properly in that route.

You cannot implement code like this.  You must register your `app.post()` handlers once and only once at server initialization time.  Do not register them inside some other event handler that gets called multiple times.

If you want to access a client's socket.io connection from within an `app.post()` handler, then you have to do things very differently.  And, similarly, you shouldn't be registering socket.io event handlers INSIDE an `app.post()` handler because you can also end up with duplicate event handlers for that too.

Event handlers for socket.io connections should be setup once when the socket connections.

Route handlers for incoming http requests should be setup once when you initialize your server.

Comment: But I need to emit and receive the message from the client everytime when I hit the button how could I implement it? Is there any alternative to it? Please give me some idea

Comment: @Arunprasath - I do not understand what you're real application question is.  If you add some text to your question describing the actual user action you're trying to implement, then I'll take a look, but this architecture is not the way to implement anything.

Comment: Whenever client turns on the remote management, The polling should start with the server ( Admin ). When the polling is started admin can send message to the client to turn on the VPN connection then send back the IP address generated by VPN back to the admin. This is what I'm trying to achieve right now I'm trying to send the static IP value but later I'll include the operations required for VPN. So basically I want to start the polling with admin when the client turns on the remote management and then admin sends message to turn on VPN, then receive the generated ip from client.

Comment: @Arunprasath - Please use the "Edit" button to put this information into your question itself.  Your question needs to be clear.

Comment: Alright! Can you provide any solution for this ?